# I am getting the error - unable to find valid certification path" in my Springtoolsuite 4(in Mac)

Tags: java, macos, rest, rest-assured, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to compile my first project in Spring tool suite4, but getting the following error -  The following artifacts could not be resolved: commons-
io:commons-io:jar:2.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:2.0.0: Could not transfer artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6 from/to central
(https://artifacts.apple.com/plugins-release): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification
path to requested target ...Also the error is pointing to the following code block in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What happens if you run the build of the project from the command line? The PKIX error is usually related to certificates not being in the keystone of the JDK that you use, but those certificates are needed to verify the connection to the URL. Maybe your local JDK install has those certs already in the keystone, so running the build locally from the command line could help.

Comment: In case that works, you can adjust the JDK that is used to run the IDE to use the same JDK that you use on the command line (by modifying the SpringToolSuite4.ini file).

Comment: Thanks it worked after I copy the certificate from local to my JRE folder.